# How do I stop the overlap of elements in an on hover transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my website I want to be able to allow the user to hover over an image and have the image zoomed in by a transition. I've been able to succeed with the implementation of the transition, however, when the image is being zoomed in, it constantly overlaps the other elements. My current layout is ordered in a grid and the container has been given the attribute overflow:hidden.

I tried to assign each element a z-index value of -1 when its being hovered, but the there is a continuous change between the layers which looks horrible. How do I allow each image to be zoomed in without overlapping into any of the other elements?

Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Syed213shah/4u0vh5Lb/

```
body {
  background-color: #800020;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}



  #box-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 600px;
    width: 75%;

  }

.container {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 2fr;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: static;

}

.item1 { 
  background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D5gQCxCW0AE0skl.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  position: relative;

}

.item1:hover {
   transform: scale(1.1); 
   z-index: -1;

}


.item2 { 
  background-image: url('https://media-public.fcbarcelona.com/20157/0/document_thumbnail/20197/172/175/246/32944044/1.0-10/32944044.jpg?t=1475841685000');
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  position: relative;


}

.item2:hover {
   transform: scale(1.1); 
   z-index: -1;
}

.item3 {
  background-image: url('https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/10/26/15721062687641.jpg');
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  position: relative;


}

.item3:hover {
   transform: scale(1.1);
   z-index: -1;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is more simple to use a pseudo-element or a inner tag (as you want) and scale this element setting its parent (our `<a>`) with `overflow:hidden;` to prevent your bug.

In my example I used a pseudoelement. I added these line of code to your CSS (I also commented some lines):

```
.container a {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container a::after {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  z-index:-1;
}

.item1::after{
  background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D5gQCxCW0AE0skl.jpg');
}

.item2::after{
  background-image: url('https://media-public.fcbarcelona.com/20157/0/document_thumbnail/20197/172/175/246/32944044/1.0-10/32944044.jpg?t=1475841685000');
}

.item3::after{
  background-image: url('https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/10/26/15721062687641.jpg');
}

.container a:hover::after{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

I didn't touch your HTML.

```css
body {
  background-color: #800020;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#box-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 600px;
  width: 75%;
}


/* https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D5gQCxCW0AE0skl.jpg  */

/* https://media-public.fcbarcelona.com/20157/0/document_thumbnail/20197/172/175/246/32944044/1.0-10/32944044.jpg?t=1475841685000 */

/* https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/10/26/15721062687641.jpg */


.container {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 2fr;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: static;
}

.item1 { 
  /*background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D5gQCxCW0AE0skl.jpg');*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  /*transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;*/ 
  position: relative;
}

/*.item1:hover {
   transform: scale(1.1); 
   z-index: -1;
}*/

.item2 { 
  /*background-image: url('https://media-public.fcbarcelona.com/20157/0/document_thumbnail/20197/172/175/246/32944044/1.0-10/32944044.jpg?t=1475841685000');*/
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  /*transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; */
  position: relative;
}

/*.item2:hover {
   transform: scale(1.1); 
   z-index: -1;
}*/

.item3 {
  /*background-image: url('https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/10/26/15721062687641.jpg');*/
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  /*transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; */
  position: relative;
}

/* -------------------------- */
/* I added these lines of code */
/* -------------------------- */

.container a {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container a::after {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out; 
  z-index:-1;
}

.item1::after{
  background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D5gQCxCW0AE0skl.jpg');
  
  /*to set a background without repetition and always horizontally center you could use also this syntaxt:
  background: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D5gQCxCW0AE0skl.jpg') 50% top no-repeat transparent;
  */
}

.item2::after{
  background-image: url('https://media-public.fcbarcelona.com/20157/0/document_thumbnail/20197/172/175/246/32944044/1.0-10/32944044.jpg?t=1475841685000');
}

.item3::after{
  background-image: url('https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/10/26/15721062687641.jpg');
}

.container a:hover::after{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* -------------------------- */
/* I added these line of code */
/* -------------------------- */

.item1 h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 500px 70px;
}

.item2 h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 200px 200px;
}

.item3 h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 185px 200px;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.bottom-height {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-align: center;
  color: #002a58;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #800020;
  position: fixed;
  top: -30px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar ul {
  height: -30px; 
  padding: 10px 0 10px 40px; 
  width: 100%; 
}

#navbar li{
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 10px 3px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navbar li a {
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(13, 11, 134);
}

#navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="full-height">
      <script src="script.js"></script>
      <div class="container">
         <a class="item1" href="https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football" style="text-decoration: none;" >
            <h2> Europe's biggest stadium  </h2>
         </a>
         <a class="item2" href="https://www.fcbarcelona.com/en/" style="text-decoration: none;" >
            <h2>European Success</h2>
         </a>
         <a class="item3" href="https://www.fcbarcelona.com/en/football/first-team/news" style="text-decoration: none;" >
            <h2>Current Squad</h2>
         </a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="https://first-website.awais.repl.co/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">Squad</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
            <a2><a>Created by Awais</a></a2>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <h1>FC Barcelona</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="bottom-height">
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: As much as I appreciate the solution, I still need help understanding why the container is using the hover and not any of the child elements, and what exactly is content responsible for in the container a class? Thanks

Comment: `.container a:hover::after` is equal to say "when I hovered on `.container a`, do something on after pseudoelement (that it is its child)". If you use a inner tag (maybe it is more simple to understand) will be `.container a:hover .inner` => "when I hovered on `.container  a`, do something on `.inner` element. So the `.container a` is important because defines the hovered area. The contain (our pseudoelement or inner tag) manages the Barcelona Team's imgs.

Comment: You're welcome. :-) OFFTOPIC: please, if you can... support another team...! ;-)

Comment: Will do my best to help

Answer (score 0):

instead of **transform: scale** on your images, perhaps using the background-size and background position might give the result you seek with a bit more control of the actual cropping you are already using.

the jsfiddle attached modifies your code with such an example. I did leave the transform scale in place for the text overlay. also note the image containers need a overflow:hidden in order to prevent hover interaction between cells.

here is your css modified accordingly;

```
body {
  background-color: #800020;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#box-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 600px;
    width: 75%;
  }

.container {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 2fr;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: static;
}

.item1 {
  background-image: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/media/D5gQCxCW0AE0skl.jpg');
 background-position: 0% 50%;
 background-size:200%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item1:hover {
   background-size:220%;
   background-position: 5% 50%;
}

.item2 {
  background-image: url('https://media-public.fcbarcelona.com/20157/0/document_thumbnail/20197/172/175/246/32944044/1.0-10/32944044.jpg?t=1475841685000');
  background-position: 0% 50%;
  background-size:165%;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item2:hover {
   background-position: 5% 50%;
   background-size:180%;
}

.item3 {
  background-image: url('https://e00-marca.uecdn.es/assets/multimedia/imagenes/2019/10/26/15721062687641.jpg');
  background-position: 0% 15%;
  background-size:175%;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item3:hover {
   background-position: 5% 15%;
   background-size:195%;
}

.item1 h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 500px 70px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.item2 h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 200px 200px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.item3 h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 185px 200px;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.item1:hover h2,
.item2:hover h2,
.item3:hover h2 {
   transform: scale(1.1);
}

.full-height {
  height: 100%;
}

.bottom-height {
  height: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-align: center;
  color: #002a58;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #800020;
  position: fixed;
  top: -30px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar ul {
  height: -30px;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navbar li{
  float: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 10px 3px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navbar li a {
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(13, 11, 134);
}

#navbar li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar .a2{
  float: right;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 10px 3px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navbar .a2 a {
  font-family: Staatliches;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(13, 11, 134);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w9n6ajq1/